# how to filter results inside where clause in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel, I am building a small application which alerts when event date is a week away from current date. Here is my controller code

```
public function index()
{

    $domain_count = domain_details::get()->count();
    $domain_alert = domain_details::
    where('domain_ex_date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
    ->get();
 }
```

The domain_ex_date is in the format (YYYY-mm-dd) stored with the help of Carbon. The line `where('domain_ex_date','>',date('Y-m-d'))` gets me whole record when the domain_ex_date is away from the current date. i.e 2017-06-12 > 2016-09-15 gets the whole record. Here what i want to do is , i want to filter and get the only records which is only a week away from the current date. How do i do this ? i have tried like subweek() and subdays() but nothing helped.

I should get the record only when it satisfies this condition `domain_ex_date - current date = 7`

Comment: do yo need the dates which have the condition (domain_ex_date - current_date) = 7 or (domain_ex_date - current_date) >= 7?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime()`:

```
domain_details:: where('domain_ex_date','<',date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+7 days")))         
              -> where('domain_ex_date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
              ->get();
```

Comment: shouldn't it be strtotime("+7 days") ?

Comment: it seems from the Question that 'domain_ex_date' is the event date which will be later than the 'current_date'. So you might add 7 days to current date and then check if the current date is larger than the event date. right?

Comment: @sha-1. oh. i thught it was created date.

Comment: this statement gets me the same results which **where('domain_ex_date','>',date('Y-m-d'))** did

Comment: @Naveen get the only records which is only a week away from the current date. Use < updated the answer

Comment: @sanzeeb Yes this works but works in a unexpected way , i have domain_ex_date = 12-05-2016 (expired). The record with the mentioned gets filtered by this approach.

Comment: @Naveen you can add another where clause exact similar to your original.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)!
Carbon is a build in date-extension ... Try it! :)

```
$week = Carbon::now()->addWeek();
$now = Carbon::now();

domain_details::where("domain_ex_date","<" $week)
    ->where("domain_ex_date", ">" $now)
    ->get()
```

Or you could also use the addDays($days) method!

```
$week = Carbon::now()->addDays(7);
```

Comment: Glad to hear.. :)

Comment: Will you please mark my answer as the right answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I used carbon and this is what worked well for me

```
 $week = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
 $now = Carbon::now();

 $domain_count = domain_details::get()->count();
 $domain_alert = domain_details::where("domain_ex_date",">", $week)
                               ->where("domain_ex_date", "<" ,$now)
                               ->get();
```